# calculate $\lim_{t\rightarrow1^+}\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\sqrt{1+\cos(\pi t)}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to calculate $$\lim_{t\rightarrow1^+}\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\sqrt{1+\cos(\pi t)}}$$? I've tried to use L'Hospital, but then I'll get

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow1^+}\frac{\pi\cos(\pi t)}{\frac{-\pi\sin(\pi t)}{2\sqrt{1+\cos(\pi t)}}}=\lim_{t\rightarrow1^+}\frac{2\pi\cos(\pi t)\sqrt{1+\cos(\pi t)}}{-\pi\sin(\pi t)}$$
and this doesn't get me further. Any ideas?

Comment: Tip: Multiply top and bottom with the denominator's conjugate and apply pythagorean theorem on the resulting denominator, as mentioned below....(I was too late)

Comment: You could compute $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 1^-}{\sin^2(\pi t)\over {1+\cos(\pi t)}}$ instead. That's easy. Then note this limit is the negative of the square of your limit.

Comment: A bit of general advice concerning l'Hopital's Rule is that radicals are its "Achilles' heel".  (The Rule should come with a warning on its label: Do Not Apply Directly to Radicals.)  The problem is just what you found it does -- derivatives of radicals tend to remain such and simply volley back and forth between numerator and denominator.  This is why we teach additional methods for dealing with indeterminate limit values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow1^+}\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\sqrt{1+\cos(\pi t)}}=\lim_{t\rightarrow1^+}\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\sqrt{1+\cos(\pi t)}}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos(\pi t)}}{\sqrt{1-\cos(\pi t)}}=\lim_{t\rightarrow1^+}\frac{\sin(\pi t)\sqrt{1-\cos(\pi t)}}{\sqrt{\sin^2(\pi t)}}$$

**P.S.** Pay attention to the sign of $\sin(\pi t)$ .

Comment: well the sign is negative, but why is this important?

Comment: @user31035 What is $\sqrt{\sin^2(\pi t)}$?

Answer (score 4):

This is not quite a solution, more of a comment about the assertion that the L'Hospital's Rule calculation 
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow1^+}\frac{\pi\cos(\pi t)}{\frac{-\pi\sin(\pi t)}{2\sqrt{1+\cos(\pi t)}}}=\lim_{t\rightarrow1^+}\frac{2\pi\cos(\pi t)\sqrt{1+\cos(\pi t)}}{-\pi\sin(\pi t)}$$
does not get us any further.

Let $L$ be the original limit, **assumed** to exist and be non-zero.  Now look at the right-hand side of the expression you reached. The $\pi$'s cancel. The term $\cos(\pi t)$ sedately approaches $-1$, cancelling the minus sign. And the rest has limit $\dfrac{1}{L}$! What you saw as a flaw becomes a virtue.

We conclude that $L=2\cdot \dfrac{1}{L}$. Thus $L=\pm \sqrt{2}$, and a quick examination of signs shows that we  need the negative one, since a little past $\pi$, the sine is negative.

I do not advocate this approach, since there are details of existence to fill in, and one could easily reach an incorrect conclusion. Anyway, there is a simple non-L'Hospital calculation that quickly yields the answer.

Comment: I have seen more of those situations, where L'Hospital "loops you around", that an equation involving limit L can then be easily set up and solved. But yes, I would certainly make a graph to see if the answer makes sense.

Comment: Often, when it looks as if we are going in circles, we **are** going in circles. But not always.

Answer (score 1):

I'll show you a trick: since $t\to 1^+$ you know that $\pi t\to \pi^+$, so $(\pi t -\pi)\to 0^+$.

First of all do the change of variable $u=\pi t-\pi$, so you get $\pi t=u-\pi$. Then $\sin(\pi t)=\sin(u-\pi)=-\sin u$ and $\cos(\pi t)=\cos(u-\pi)=-\cos u$. Thus your limit becomes

$$
\lim_{u\to 0^+}\frac{-\sin u}{\sqrt{1-\cos u}}=
-\lim_{u\to 0^+}\sqrt{\frac{\sin^2 u}{1-\cos u}}=
-\lim_{u\to 0^+}\sqrt{1+\cos u}=-\sqrt{2}
$$

The first equality is justified because $\sin u>0$ for $0<u<\pi$ (and you're interested in a right neighborhood of $0$).

Limits at zero are "psychologically" better, aren't they? There's really no difference with doing the limit at $\pi$ or using $\pi t$, but the region around $0$ is better known.

Answer (score 0):

In the original expression, use the half angle equation in the denominator, and the double angle equation in the numerator. Then $ cos(\pi t/2) $ cancels, and the original expression equals minus $\sqrt 2 sin(\pi t/2) $